# Class 'Michielfb\Time' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Hi I'm using laravel nova and [michielfb/laravel-nova-time-field](https://packagist.org/packages/michielfb/laravel-nova-time-field) package.
This is my code.

```
use Michielfb\Time;

Time::make('Time')->format('HH:mm');
```

But I'm getting this error.

> Class 'Michielfb\Time' not found

It would be great if someone can help.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: So sorry I did but still same error :(

Comment: what's your laravel version? is the package auto-discovered?

Comment: Can you verify the file is in your /vendors directory?

Comment: have you registered your package in your config/app.php?

Comment: it's in vendors derectory. But I didn't registered since it wasn't mentioned in doc. laravel version is 5.7.28

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the namespace definition from the [Time](https://github.com/michielfb/laravel-nova-time-field/blob/1.0.0/src/Time.php) class, the `use` statement should be:

```php
use Michielfb\Time\Time;
```

and not

```php
use Michielfb\Time;
```

The example in the readme seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks so much you saved lot of time for me

Comment: ah sure sorry :)